# Any indication that Gustavo Fring might have had a family of his own?

Tags: breaking-bad

In Breaking Bad, as far as I understood, Gustavo Fring never really had a family of his own. It is logical from one perspective not to have anyone valuable to you when doing business of the sort. However, following Gustavo's ability to keep his enemies close and display himself as a low profile business owner with normal life, I start to think that he should have had a family. Have there been any hints about his personal life, any ideas, thoughts or assumptions?

Comment: He mentions 'daughters' when Walter joins him for dinner..

Comment: As for his personal life, there were some assumptions that his actions suggest his relationship with Max was beyond mere friendship. But with no real proof, they just remain assumptions. The actor didn't verify it and said that he and Vince Gilligan chose to keep it vague.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is taken directly from the [Breaking Bad Wiki](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Gustavo_Fring), which is usually pretty spot on:

> Gus also claims to have children, though they have never been seen nor anybody else in his family life has been revealed.

Comment: Has this been mentioned in the movie?

Comment: TV show?  Yes, he mentions his kids, but not how many he has.  Also, if you watch the episode Abiquiú (S3E11), that's the one where Gus invites Walt to his house.  You can see some kids toys laying around.

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant  to say the show. I wonder if it was a way for Gustavo to comfort Walter during the dinner, to make himself look as normal as Walter is. First time I've seen that I took it as Gustavo's trick.